# CKEditor - No toolbars

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So I got a `textarea` with `CKEditor` plugin but I just want it clean, without anything. No toolbars and no status or whatever bar. It´s simple but I can´t find it on docs or web!

My `CKEditor` is started with:

`$('#texto').ckeditor({skin:'office2003'});`

Comment: I can't imagine what the point of having it without any toolbar is, but I'm sure you have a reason for asking.

Comment: @DoozerBlake Cause I got a `textarea` and I need to show formatted text and `CKEditor` put the `p` for me but I don't need any tool for now, maybe in future (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the `config.js` file in the directory where you put the source files to specify custom toolbars.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
   config.toolbar = 'Custom'; //makes all editors use this toolbar
   config.toolbar_Custom = []; //define an empty array or whatever buttons you want.
};
```

See the [developer's guide](http://docs.cksource.com/Talk%3aCKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, is that I was searching for.

Answer (score 16):

Actually, the right way for it is simply removing the plugins that render these features:

```
config.removePlugins = 'toolbar,elementspath,resize';
```

With the new CKEditor 4, you may even build your own editor without these plugins, making your the editor code smaller: http://ckeditor.com/builder

Comment: I tried the accepted answer and it shows empty toolbar instead of hiding it. This one is definitely a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @wsanwille answer to also hide the toolbar.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('description', {
   toolbar: 'Custom', //makes all editors use this toolbar
   toolbarStartupExpanded : false,
   toolbarCanCollapse  : false,
   toolbar_Custom: [] //define an empty array or whatever buttons you want.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With CKE 4 or newer, you can use below lines to config your CKE locally:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 CKEDITOR.replace('textArea-id');
 CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [['Bold','Italic','Underline']] ;
 CKEDITOR.config.uiColor = '#fff';
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like that? The blank square is ckeditor.

[image: [my ckeditor]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfgBv.png)