# Can I use CKEditor without a toolbar?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

(Possible duplicate: [CKEditor - No toolbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344567/ckeditor-no-toolbars))

I'd like to create a CKEditor instance without a toolbar. I tried defining an empty toolbar to use in the instance's config

```
oConfigName.toolbar = 'Custom';
oConfigName.toolbar_Custom = [];
```

but I get a small empty toolbar by my instance, instead of no toolbar.

I am using [inline editing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) with CKEditor4.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Wow :) This is something that we haven't thought of while implementing toolbar. But I've just checked that you can remove toolbar plugin, because it isn't required by any other plugin.

So [build your own](http://ckeditor.com/builder) CKEditor package without toolbar or use `removePlugins` configuration - e.g.:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable', {
    removePlugins: 'toolbar'
} );
```

**Update:** In CKEditor 4.1 the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) was introduced. In its [automatic mode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter-section-2) it is configured by buttons which are loaded to toolbar. Without `toolbar` plugin ACF is not configured, so one need to do this on his own:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable', {
    removePlugins: 'toolbar',
    allowedContent: 'p h1 h2 strong em; a[!href]; img[!src,width,height];'
} );
```

Comment: great answer, removing the toolbar plugin worked perfect.  As for ACF, everyone will call this taboo, but you can set ***`config.allowedContent` to `true`*** if you don't feel like listing almost every html element that has, does, and will ever exist.

Comment: Hehe :) When you want to allow *"almost every html element"*, then it's definitely acceptable to disable ACF.

Comment: I need to disable all of the following plugins in order to get rid of toolbar: `removePlugins: 'toolbar, pastefromword, tableselection, uploadwidget, clipboard, pastetext, widget, uploadimage',`

Comment: doesnt allow `extraAllowedContent: 'style;*[id,rel](*){*}'` anyway

Answer (score 7):

In CKEditor 4.9.2:

When you instanciate the editor, set toolbar option:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    ...
    toolbar: []
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I have seen:

**1) Using the `removePlugins` option and just remove the toolbar:**

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'textarea', {
    removePlugins: 'toolbar',
    allowedContent: 'p h1 h2 strong em; a[!href]; img[!src,width,height];'
} );
```

**2) Using CSS - Not the standard approach: (*little tricky*)**

Just make css to display:none the toolbar, like

```
.cke_inner {
    display: none;
}
```

In version 4.13, you can hide the entire top bar containing the toolbar:

```
.cke_inner .cke_top {
    display: none;
}
```

or hide only the toolbar but keep a strip of color at the top:

```
.cke_inner .cke_top .cke_toolbox {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: The CSS option works best for me. It does not require a rebuild. Moreover, the keyboard shortcuts still work.

Answer (score 2):

I do this in ckeditor5:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {
        licenseKey: '',
        toolbar: [],

    } )
    .then( editor => {
        window.editor = editor;
        editor.isReadOnly = true;


    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( 'Oops, something went wrong!' );
        console.error( 'Please, report the following error on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues with the build id and the error stack trace:' );
        console.warn( 'Build id: efxy8wt6qchd-qhxgzg9ulnyo' );
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

if you want to remove border around ckeditor 5 do this:

```
 <style>
        .ck{
            border:0px !important;
        }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've turned off everything except italics, bold and underlined with this config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.autoParagraph = false;
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Strike,Subscript,Superscript,RemoveFormat';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this this line in to ***config.js*** file

```
config.removePlugins= 'toolbar'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added new function into my project for hide/show of the toolbar.

```js
function onClickToolbarButton() {
    var bar = document.getElementById("cke_1_top");
    if(bar.style.display == "none"){
        bar.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        bar.style.display = "none";
    }

    //resize web page
    //onresize();
}
```

Call this function every time, if you want hide/show toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

In CKEditor 5 the easiest way without changing configuration or editor behaviour is to hide the toolbar using CSS:

```
.ck.ck-editor__top {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: none` using CSS with their ids or their class:

Example:

```
#cke_19, #cke_18, #cke_22, #cke_46, #cke_45 {
    display:none;
}
```

`#cke_45` is for link and `#cke_46` for unlink

To turn them off one by one

Answer (score 0):

More correct way in CKEditor 5:

```
editor.ui.view.stickyPanel.element.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: It works better when you have several CKEditor instances and don't need to hide the toolbar for all of them. This code only hides current CKEditor instance toolbar

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [official documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/read-only.html#hiding-toolbar-in-read-only-mode) when using CKEditor 5. It covers hiding toolbar especialy when using read-only mode.

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        // ...
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        const toolbarElement = editor.ui.view.toolbar.element;

        editor.on( 'change:isReadOnly', ( evt, propertyName, isReadOnly ) => {
            if ( isReadOnly ) {
                toolbarElement.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                toolbarElement.style.display = 'flex';
            }
        } );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

So, to apply styles in readonly mode this works for `CKEditor 4.11.4`

```
  CKEDITOR.replace(inputId, {
    extraAllowedContent: 'style;*[id,rel](*){*}',
    readOnly: true,
    // removePlugins: 'toolbar',
    toolbarCanCollapse: true, //Button to toggle toolbar (show/hide) 
    toolbarStartupExpanded: false, 
    // toolbar: [],
    // allowedContent: 'p h1 h2 strong em; a[!href]; img[!src,width,height];',
  });
```

commented rows do not make any sense or even wasting result