# CKEDITOR inline editor without toolbar blinking icons

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have CKEDITOR in my webpage to allow users edit HTML paragraphs, headers, etc. for custom editable content. I looked up into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611386/can-i-use-ckeditor-without-a-toolbar)  to remove inline editor default toolbar, as long as I'm creating my own "toolbar" into a floating dialog.

Using the answer into the link I posted, when I try to edit any element doing double-click (because I attached a `dblclick` event to all elements that creates a CKEDITOR instance to that element) it works perfect, but after 2-3 seconds my icons for boldering text, changing alignment, etc. in dialog blink (disappear and reappear) as if you reloaded something into the document.

Anyone knows why? It's pretty frustrating to see like something is reloaded, but it is not (apparently).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I couldn't post my code before, because I was working. Here is what I have:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
if (!CKEDITOR.instances.editorId) {
    CKEDITOR.inline('editorId', {
        plugins: 'toolbar,basicstyles,wysiwygarea,indent,link,list,find',
        autoParagraph: true,
        allowedContent: true,
        forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
        disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
        resize_enabled: false,
        stylesSet: 'default:styles.js',
        contentsCss: ['http://www.youblue.es/css/fonts.css'],
        title: false,
        removePlugins: 'toolbar'
    }); // I loaded all config here, taking advantage that I had to remove toolbar
}
```

And here is what I tried so far without the expected results:

```
CKEDITOR.appendTo('editorId', {
    plugins: 'toolbar,basicstyles,wysiwygarea,indent,link,list,find',
    autoParagraph: true,
    allowedContent: true,
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
    disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
    resize_enabled: false,
    stylesSet: 'default:styles.js',
    contentsCss: ['http://www.youblue.es/css/fonts.css'],
    title: false,
    removePlugins: 'toolbar'
}, '');
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CKEDITOR.inline('editorId', {
    plugins: 'toolbar,basicstyles,wysiwygarea,indent,link,list,find',
    autoParagraph: true,
    allowedContent: true,
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
    disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
    resize_enabled: false,
    stylesSet: 'default:styles.js',
    contentsCss: ['http://www.youblue.es/css/fonts.css'],
    title: false,
    removePlugins: 'toolbar'
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CKEDITOR.replace('editorId', {
    plugins: 'toolbar,basicstyles,wysiwygarea,indent,link,list,find',
    autoParagraph: true,
    allowedContent: true,
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
    disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
    resize_enabled: false,
    stylesSet: 'default:styles.js',
    contentsCss: ['http://www.youblue.es/css/fonts.css'],
    title: false,
    removePlugins: 'toolbar'
});
```

The most accurate was the `inline` function call, but as I mentioned, the icons blink when the editor loaded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to know why the downvote for this question =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I found a solution. Seems like something went wrong in my CKEditor build when trying to remove toolbar plugin, but it worked when I removed `'toolbar'` from this line in config:

```
CKEDITOR.inline('editorId', {
    // ...
    plugins: 'toolbar,basicstyles,wysiwygarea,indent,link,list,find', // <- This one
    // ...
}
```

And stopped blinking icons when I removed this line:

```
removePlugins: 'toolbar'
```

Seems like it reloads the editor when you use `removePlugins`, but only when removing `toolbar` plugin. It didn't remove toolbar without removing the plugin manually maybe because something went wrong/in conflict with CKEditor when loading. To avoid that, just be sure that all your JS are loaded in the correct order, check that JS paths are the right ones and check that you don't have any JS overwritting other JS.

I felt pretty stupid and newbie when I found the solution after posting here. I felt ashamed =(

Sorry guys.