# Rails 4: Simple Rich Text Editor (currently using text area)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently using a `f.text_area` for users to enter text inside a form. Since those entries can be quite long, I want to offer my users to format the input with bold, italic and underlines.

Ideally, users access the formatting options with the common `cmd+b`, `cmd+i` and `cmd+u`.

I know about `contenteditable` but since this can't be applied to a textarea inside a form but only to a div, this does not seem to work inside a rails form.

What other options are there that play nicely with `form_for`?

Comment: maybe you need [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)

Answer (score 3):

**Ruby on Rails Solutions**

1. rails-ckeditor
2. Mercury
3. rails_tiny_mce
4. redactor-rails

I personally suggest Mercury, there's also a Railscast available for this specific gem :)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want a toolbar at all, I simply want the hotkeys to make text bold and italic – is it possible to customise Mercury like that?

Comment: Unfortunately no. At least not from what I know. I suggest you then use `https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor` as it'll be integrated in your form. The gem automatically picks up `simple_form` as well as `formtastic` forms so ease the process :)

Comment: Oh wait, I just saw your comment to the answer that suggests CKEditor. I doubt something like that already lives in a gem. Your best approach is probably using Javascript to apply certain behaviors to selected text. Here's a similar answer that might be what you're looking for: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880271/make-selected-text-bold-unbold`.

Answer (score 1):

We've implemented [`CKEditor`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) before - here's how to do it (I can delete if you wish):

```
#Gemfile
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.1.6'

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require ckeditor/init

#config/initializers/asset.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/*)

#app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  ...
};
```

The beauty of this gem is it [integrates with `Paperclip`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#activerecord--paperclip), allowing you to upload files directly to the server (I can provide code if required).

You can also change the toolbar & styling to be anything you like.

Although it's quite bloated, it's the best we've used. The other good one you'll benefit from is [`redactor`](https://imperavi.com/redactor/), although it's premium and I've not seen a direct integration into Rails.

Comment: I don't want a toolbar at all, I simply want the hotkeys to make text bold and italic – is that possible to customise CKEditor like that?

Comment: [I believe so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611386/can-i-use-ckeditor-without-a-toolbar)